# <address1/> What value is in address

Tags: xslt

I have an XSLT statement as follows:

```
<xsl:when test="address1 != ' '">
```

My incoming XML  the address node is as follows:

```
<address1/>
```

The node exists and the xsl statement seems to work sometimes, but it doesn't always work, it is giving me inconsistent results.   I am checking the address1 node and if it is spaces, then I check address2 node, if it is not spaces I move it up to address1 output field if address1 input is spaces.   Our customers are very inconsistent when entering addresses and our vendor requires address1 to be valid.   Thanks for any help.

Comment: Good question, +1, as result of which you'll learn to use the standard XPath function `normalize-space()`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with checking against a string is that you actually check for text within all descendants of the element, so `<foo><bar>test</bar></foo>` would fail the test `foo = ''`, because the text `test` exists within the tree.

A more conclusive test is:
`address1[not(text()) and not(*)]`

This passes only where there is neither text nor child elements within the address element.

Answer (score 0):

The node is empty.

You are testing for it not being a single space `' '`, if it is an empty node the test will succeed.

To test that the node is empty you can do this:

```
<xsl:when test="address1 = ''">
```

Comment: How do you check for an empty node

Answer (score 0):

A self-closing tag should have no content, so checking for `''` would be the proper way to go. Doing `'[space]'` implies that the tag is actually `<address1>[space]</address1>`, which is no longer self closing.

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling us enough about your code for us to reliably tell you what's wrong with it. Don't be so reticent! There could be all sorts of problems that aren't evident from a tiny snippet, e.g. using the wrong context item.

One piece of advice, though: avoid the "!=" operator (which appeared in your example). Usually you want `not(author='')` rather than `author!=''`. They mean the same thing if there is exactly one author element, but they have different meanings if there is no author element or if there is more than one. The expression `author!=''` is true if there is at least one author element whose value is not the empty string; the expression `not(author='')` is true if there is no author element whose value is the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

**To check if an element's string value is non-empty and non-whitespace-only, use**:

```
string-length(normalize-space(address1)) > 0
```

The standard XPath function [**`normalize-space`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space)`($s)` takes a string `$s` as an argument and returns another string produced from `$s` in which all leading and trailing whitespace characters are removed and any group of adjacent interim whitespace characters is replaced by a single space-character.

This means that the result of `normalize-space()` when applied on a string that contains only white-space characters, is the empty string (having `string-length()` of `0`).

The XPath expression above is testing if the result of applying the `normalize-space()` function to the string-value of `address1` has positive (`> 0`) length -- this means that the string value of `address1` contains at least one non-whitespace character.